# Firebase.DatabaseException ArticleModel does not define a no-argument constructor

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i kept getting error
Firebase.DatabaseException
"ArticleModel does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped."

when i was doing at android studio i just want to use ArticleModel data class and i didn't use nothing else. and i didn't write nothing else.
what am i have to do??

here is my ArticleModel.class

```
data class ArticleModel(
    val sellerID: String,
    val title: String,
    val createAt: Long,
    val price: String,
    val imageUrl: String
)
```